# Azure AD user's group membership

Tags: windows-10, azure, azure-activedirectory

I'm trying to figure out if a user who logs into Azure AD has the following group:

NT AUTHORITY\Cloud Account Authentication

I don't have Azure AD, so I can't check.

So, could someone who has a Azure AD login on a Windows 10 client please run a "whoami /groups" and tell me if that group appears in the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right!

Once we login a Windows 10 machine (Azure AD joined) with an Azure AD account, the current logon user has the group you mentioned: **`NT AUTHORITY\Cloud Account Authentication`**.

Here is my test result for your reference:

[image]